# How to make a buildable publishable library with Nx that is framework agnostic for browser and node.js

Tags: npm, build, dependency-management, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have a monorepo (Nx Workspace) that has many libraries that were generated with @nrwl/js. These libraries depend on each other. They are small utility libraries that I intend to publish on NPM as separate packages.

According to Nx docs:

> @nrwl/js is particularly useful if you want to
>
> - Create framework agnostic, just plain TypeScript libraries within an existing Nx workspace (say to use in your React, Node or Angular app)
> - Publish TypeScript packages to NPM

Yet, I now realize that the build command associated with @nrwl/js does not take into account a library's dependencies on other libraries in order to include them as `peerDependencies` into its publishable package.json. It also looks like it is making just a simple commonjs build that would be compatible with node.js but not with browsers.

I know that @nrwl/angular takes care of all that stuff for you when you build a library with it if you had marked it as publishable. My question is how do I get the same behavior but for a library that is not meant for Angular but for general purpose Javascript use in any framework or environment.

It's still early in development so if a solution to my problem would involve regenerating the libs using some other Nx generator, it wouldn't be too much of a hassle for me to do so, and I'd consider it.

#### Edit

I have since changed the build executor to @nrwl/node, which has the `buildable` and `publishable` options and behave the way I need.

I believe that @nrwl/js will eventually gain that ability but as of 2022-01-05 it didn't have it. For now, someone looking to publish libraries on NPM probably should use @nrwl/node to generate his new library projects and not @nrwl/js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a NPM package as a "universal package" to be consumed by Node.js and the browser, you would need to build it as [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), to cover most consumer environments.

Though modern browsers support ES modules (`import` and `export`), you might need extra setup steps to consume them.

Comment: Right. I thought so too. And it looks like Nx doesn't have an executor that will do that out of the box.

Comment: I would also be interested in finding an executor for that, please let us know if you do.